# Unable to sync calendar to outlook

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

Recently my company kept policy to disable PST. From that point we are unable to sync calendars from SharePoint to Outlook

We are using 2013

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like changing the PST setting in the GPO from `No PST's allowed`
>   to `Allow Sharing-Exclusive PST files only` did the trick.
>
> I think you should check below articles for this
>
> [Outlook 2010 Internet Calendar Group policy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/eee18ae0-3612-484c-a0d7-723719a58ba5/outlook-2010-internet-calendar-group-policy)
>
> [How to use Group Policy to disable .PST files in Outlook 2010](http://exchange-2010-info.blogspot.ca/2010/03/how-to-use-group-policy-to-disable-pst.html)

I have found above information on [this blog](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28219273/Can-you-block-PST-file-creation-and-still-allow-Sharepoint-and-Internet-Calendar-creation.html) but it is for **Outlook 2010**.

I hope it helps you...!

Comment: Have you tried above solution? Did it worked for you?